# ng-template with mat-table inside ng-table-virtual-scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am trying to use the content from ng-template to render inside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport (from this library: [ng-table-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/diprokon/ng-table-virtual-scroll)) but I am getting an error

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport tvsItemSize [footerEnabled]="true"
                             [headerEnabled]="false">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="operationTable;context:{$implicit:operationTableDataSource}">
    </ng-container>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

<ng-template #operationTable>
    <mat-table>
        .....
    </mat-table>
</ng-template>
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> '_switchDataSource')
> at TableItemSizeDirective.ngAfterContentInit (ng-table-virtual-scroll.mjs:186:40)

If I don't use ng-template and copy the content directly, it all works fine. For ex; below code works fine

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport tvsItemSize [footerEnabled]="true"
                             [headerEnabled]="false">
    <mat-table>
        .....
    </mat-table>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Does anyone know how to use ng-template with cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport or is this a limitation of cdk-virtual-scroll? I can add more information if required but I hope the question and problem is clear.

Comment: My final approach was to go with the workaround mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/diprokon/ng-table-virtual-scroll/issues/98)

Answer (score 1):

Your title and your post do not mention anything about the current library you're using, which is `ng-table-virtual-scroll`. Very misleading I would say.

I went to the [library source code](https://github.com/diprokon/ng-table-virtual-scroll/blob/1922b4dbf3b918c581a33f4d4da7800e0e684fa8/projects/ng-table-virtual-scroll/src/lib/table-item-size.directive.ts#L75) and what they do is they get the table by using `ContentChild` which [doesn't work with `ngTemplateOutlet`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842)

```
//look for the MatTable under the directive
 @ContentChild(MatTable, { static: false })
  table: MatTable<any>;
```

Since this is the internal lib code, you won't be able to change it, so the answer is no, you can't use `ngTemplateOutlet` with this library

Comment: First of all thanks for editing the question to include the library name and for taking a look into a library code. I was looking for a work around and I found a similar issue https://github.com/diprokon/ng-table-virtual-scroll/issues/98. There is a workaround mentioned and it's close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was using an older version ng-table-virtual-scroll, which did not work with my Angular version https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-table-virtual-scroll